# python: searching list of objects for certain attribute value

Tags: python, oop, contains

I have an class for twitter tweets that looks like this, I'm thinking there probably is a good fix for this

```py
class tweet:

    def __init__(self, userName, likes, replys, retweets, message, ID):
        self.userName = userName
        self.likes = likes
        self.replys = replys
        self.retweets = retweets
        self.message = message
        self.lenMessage = len(self.message)
        self.mentions = self.message.count('@')
        self.hastags = self.message.count('#')
        self.ID = ID
```

And in my `main class` I have a list of this kind of object. I want to be able to look in this list whether there are any in the tweets in the list that have a certain ID, and i just cant figure out exactly how to formulate this:

```
from Students import tweet


listoftweets = []

t1 = tweet("ding", 100, 5, 1,"a message",   1906961683)
t2 = tweet("dong" ,5, 5, 5, "another message", 190696969)
t3 = tweet("bang", 1, 1, 1, "anew message",2003)
t4 = tweet("fest" ,3, 3, 3,"a message", 1930)
listoftweets.append(t1)
listoftweets.append(t2)
listoftweets.append(t3)
listoftweets.append(t4)



# now if i wanted to check if there is a object with the attribute ID = 2003
#how would i do this?
if listoftweets.__contains__():
    print("the list does contain specified ID")
```

Thank you all very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for l in listoftweets:
    if l.ID == "###":  # ID to be matched
        print("List does contain specified ID")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: use `namedtuples` instead. The following works:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Base:
    @property
    def lenMessage(self):
        return len(self.message)

    @property
    def mentions(self):
        return self.message.count('@')

    @property
    def hashtags(self):
        return self.message.count('#')

class Tweet(Base, namedtuple('BaseTweet', 'userName likes replies retweets message ID')):
    pass

listoftweets = [
    Tweet("ding", 100, 5, 1,"a message",   1906961683),
    Tweet("dong" ,5, 5, 5, "another message", 190696969),
    Tweet("bang", 1, 1, 1, "anew message",2003),
    Tweet("fest" ,3, 3, 3,"a message", 1930)
]

found = [tweet for tweet in listoftweets if tweet.ID == 2003]
print(found)
```

This yields

```
[Tweet(userName='bang', likes=1, replies=1, retweets=1, message='anew message', ID=2003)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A method like this could help:

```
def get_tweet(id):
    for tweet in listoftweets:
        if tweet.ID == id:
            return tweet
```